# Jenkins job to store and send http POST requests

Tags: http, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, queue, jenkins-plugins

For my incoming write traffic via HTTP POST API, I need to maintain the order of writes. For this, I need to create a Jenkins Job that gets triggered via remote API call on each request.

My question is, does Jenkins have a readily-available plugin to do this? Is there any such thing as a Queue in Jenkins that stores API requests and keeps triggering a job ( which will create the relevant request and send it ) while the queue is not empty?

In case of failure, I need to retry and hold the remaining requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trigger Jobs(Remote or manually) the Jobs will be queued up. Unless you have configured parallel execution with multiple Job executors, the Job queue will be processed in order and within each Job you can specify what you want to do on failure.

Having said that there is no way in Jenkins to just store HTTP requests.(At least OOB) and trigger Jobs based on that.